# Is there a python function to get the combinations of json data?

Tags: python, json, combinations

In the json data below, I need to get the combination of questions and choices (you can find them inside "Options": []).
There are 3 questions, and first one has 2 choices, the rest two has 3 choices, there should be total 2 x 3 x 3 = 18 combinations. Is there a function to do it or need to write a loop? **I need to do it in python**.

Combination examples:

1. Q1 **C1** + Q2 C1 + Q3 C1
2. Q1 **C2** + Q2 C1 + Q3 C1
3. Q1 C1 + Q2 **C2** + Q3 C1
   ...

They result should be similar to these:

1. Color: **red**, material: metal, finish: matte
2. Color: **green**, material: metal, finish: matte
3. Color: red, material: **rubber**, finish: matte

...

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Options": [
        {
            "OptionId": 123,
            "Question": "Color:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 333,
                    "Choice": "red",
                    "Url": "color/red/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 334,
                    "Choice": "green",
                    "Url": "color/green/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "OptionId": 223,
            "Question": "material:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 223,
                    "Choice": "metal",
                    "Url": "material/metal/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 227,
                    "Choice": "rubber",
                    "Url": "material/rubber/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 229,
                    "Choice": "glass",
                    "Url": "material/glass/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "OptionId": 123,
            "Question": "finish:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "matte",
                    "Url": "finish/matte/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "glossy",
                    "Url": "finish/glossy/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "mix",
                    "Url": "finish/mix/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        }

    ]
    
}
```

I have more than 10k json data and each has different number of questions/choices, this is just one example.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `itertools.product()`

Comment: This looks helpful. So first step is to extract choices into list first?

Comment: Sry for confusing, just corrected the description part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a python function to get the combinations of json data?

To my knowledge there isn't a ready-made function which directly takes JSON data, but it's not too hard to first load JSON into Python objects and then combine them.

```
import json
o = json.loads("""
{
    "Success": true,
    "Options": [
        {
            "OptionId": 123,
            "Question": "Color:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 333,
                    "Choice": "red",
                    "Url": "color/red/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 334,
                    "Choice": "green",
                    "Url": "color/green/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "OptionId": 223,
            "Question": "material:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 223,
                    "Choice": "metal",
                    "Url": "material/metal/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 227,
                    "Choice": "rubber",
                    "Url": "material/rubber/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 229,
                    "Choice": "glass",
                    "Url": "material/glass/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "OptionId": 123,
            "Question": "finish:",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "matte",
                    "Url": "finish/matte/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "glossy",
                    "Url": "finish/glossy/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                },
                {
                    "ChoiceId": 123,
                    "Choice": "mix",
                    "Url": "finish/mix/",
                    "Exceptions": []
                }
            ]

        }

    ]
    
}              """)
# now we have the JSON data in the Python object o
questions = [oo["Question"] for oo in o["Options"]]
# now we have the questions = ['Color:', 'material:', 'finish:']
choices = [[c["Choice"] for c in oo["Choices"]] for oo in o["Options"]]
# now we have the choices = [['red', 'green'],
#                            ['metal', 'rubber', 'glass'],
#                            ['matte', 'glossy', 'mix']]

# a well-known recursive algorithm for the cartesian product
# (could instead use itertools.product() as suggested)
def products(cs):
    if cs:
        for c in cs[-1]:
            for p in products(cs[:-1]): yield p+[c]
    else: yield []

cnt = 0
for p in products(choices): # count and print each result in the desired format
    cnt += 1
    print("%d."%cnt, ", ".join([" ".join(qc) for qc in zip(questions, p)]))
```